# Can vector.back() be used to assign a value to the last element of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have some code that needs to assign the first and last elements of a vector as a special case.

Is somevector.back() an lvalue? Will the following code work?

```
some_vector.front()=first_value;
some_vector.back()=last_value;
```

Comment: I don't think so, but have you tried?

Comment: Tried a reference? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back

Comment: -1 because it takes 5 seconds to look it up on cppreference and look at the return type. Unless of course you did and were confused about something.

Comment: @Pubby: I did look it up and was confused.

Comment: Also, that cppreference article didn't answer my question either. Does `return *tmp` mean that I can assign a value to it? I was under the impression that something returned by a function couldn't be assigned *to*. Also, the example only uses myvector.back() as an rvalue.

Comment: It says quite clearly that the signature is `reference back();`... One would hope that `reference` has some meaning to you. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I thought I was, but upon closer inspection I realized that I had confused them with pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Good question imho. It is easier to look up on SE and easier to understand an answer like "Yes it can", especially when you are tired. Refusing to answer and / or frowning upon simple questions only makes answers incur latency. If SE was all about self independence there would be only one question and one answer:
Q: How to do this?
A: RTFM and figure it out!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes it can, as it returns a reference to the last element. Better make sure it's not empty first!